# JQuery Autocomplete & Classic ASP

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm frustrated to heck as this is inexplicable!  This code works:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I place the necessary code in another page, it doesn't work!!  I've ensured jquery only loads once and moved some of the code from top to bottom and nothing works!  Is there anything else i may have missed?  Here's my line of code it should work with (maybe something in here stops it?)

```
<input id="dept" name="dept" type="text" class="rounded" placeholder="e.g. Production" autocomplete="off" required>
```

Has anyone else come across such issues?

Comment: Did you change the script hook from `#autocomplete` to `#dept` to match your input id change?   `$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({...});` is only going to be listening for `<input id="autocomplete">` not `<input id="dept">`

Comment: Can you explain what is different about the "other" page?

Comment: @briansol yes I made sure that the #autocomplete was the id within the <input> tag.

Comment: @JamesLawruk The other page is just an Classic ASP script which has multiple actions using POST but there is already some jquery/javascript running performing other jobs - but as far as I know none of those will interfere with the "dept" input

Comment: Try copying the HTML source from the ASP page into an HTML page. Then start removing sections of the HTML until you are left with just the code you provided here. Hopefully you will discover what is breaking it.

Comment: asp/php/whateverp has no effect on the front end... it's all HTML in the end.  I would suggest pulling out the other JS, and re-introducing it block by block until it breaks again.   Also, check the F12 console for error messages

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I shall try those today